# Find any 2 objects in a list matching criteria in one iteration

Tags: kotlin, collections

I have a list of custom objects. I would like to retrieve any 2 that meet 2 different conditions.
E.g.
Assume

```
class Person {  
  val age: Int  
  //etc  
}
```

And I have a `List<Person>`. I would like to get 2 `Person` that have `age == 21` or `age == 31`
I know I can do a loop for that and `break` using some flag once I find both, but I was wondering if there was some more Kotlin idiomatic way for this instead of:

```
var p1: Person?  
var p2: Person?  
list.forEach{  
  if(it.age == 21) {  
      p1 = it  
       
  }
  else if(it.age == 31) {  
      p2 = it  
  }  
  if(p1 != null && p2 != null) break  
}
```

Comment: Must the two entries you find satisfy a different condition each, or could they both satisfy the same condition?

Comment: @gidds: Now they can't satisfy the same condition. 2 objects and 2 different conditions. Any 2 that are found first meeting the criteria

Comment: easiest way would be to use two `.find{ it.age == fizz }`, don't need to make your own iteration or anything.

Comment: @Alex.T:  Yes that would be 2 iterations which is not efficient for big lists. I was wondering if it was doable with one without resorting to Java style code.

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of 2 possible solutions:

1. An inefficient but simple way (2 partial iterations)

```
    val list = listOf(Person(21), Person(23), Person(31), Person(20))
    
    var p1: Person? = list.find{ it.age == 21 }
    var p2: Person? = list.find{ it.age == 31 }
```

This will iterate twice, but will stop the iteration as soon as a result is found.

2. Based on your own solution, only iterates once

```
    val list = listOf(Person(21), Person(23), Person(31), Person(20))
    
    var p1: Person? = null
    var p2: Person? = null
    
    //forEach is a method, not an actual loop, you can't break out of it, this is a bypass (you can also enclose it into a fun and return from there to act as a break)
    run loop@{
        list.forEach {
            when {
                p1 == null && it.age == 21 -> p1 = it
                p2 == null && it.age == 31 -> p2 = it
            }
            if (p1 != null && p2 != null) return@loop
        }
    }
```

The `p1 == null` check will make is so that we don't reasign the same value multiple times, thus getting the first result. It is better even if we aren't necessarily looking for the first result, since it won't make multiple assignments.

Ps: both solutions will leave you with nullable `p1` and `p2`, you must remember to deal with that accordingly afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

No, you are trying to do quite a specific operation, so I don't think there is a built-in function and you will need to implement it yourself. Since you want to only iterate the list once, I think it would be best to:

1. Implement it with traditional list iteration
2. Wrap it up in a generic extension function for idiomatic Kotlin use

```
data class Person(val age: Int)

fun <T> Iterable<T>.findFirstTwo(
    predicateA: (T) -> Boolean,
    predicateB: (T) -> Boolean
): Pair<T, T> {
    var first: T? = null
    var second: T? = null
    val iterator = iterator()

    var remainingPredicate: (T) -> Boolean = { false }

    while (first == null && iterator.hasNext()) {
        val item = iterator.next()
        when {
            predicateA(item) -> {
                first = item
                remainingPredicate = predicateB
            }
            predicateB(item) -> {
                first = item
                remainingPredicate = predicateA
            }
        }
    }

    while (second == null && iterator.hasNext()) {
        val item = iterator.next()
        if (remainingPredicate(item)) {
            second = item
        }
    }

    require(first != null && second != null) { "Input does not satisfy predicates" }

    return Pair(first, second)
}

fun main() {
    val people = (1..20).map { Person(it) }

    val (seven, twelve) = people.findFirstTwo({ it.age == 12 }, { it.age == 7 })
    val (one, nineteen) = people.findFirstTwo({ it.age == 1 }, { it.age == 19 })

    val error = try {
        people.findFirstTwo({ it.age == 100 }, { it.age == 3 })
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.message
    }

    println(one)
    println(seven)
    println(twelve)
    println(nineteen)
    print(error)

}
```

Output:

```
Person(age=1)
Person(age=7)
Person(age=12)
Person(age=19)
Input does not satisfy predicates
```

Answer (score 1):

As a lot of people mentioned that `find` will probably be the best solution for this kind of problem but we will have to use it twice, once for `21` and other time for `31`.

even though `find` will return a single object: `<T> Iterable<T>.find(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): T?`
it doesn't mean we can't find another one in the same iteration.

for example:

```
var ageParam = -1

var p1: Person? = null
var p2: Person? = list.find { person ->
    p1?.let {
        //p1 - the first person found, now we will iterate until age == ageParam(21/31)
        person.age == ageParam
    } ?: run {
        //p1 - the first person hasn't found yet.
        if (person.age == 21) {
            p1 = person // saving person
            ageParam = 31 // setting next condition to test
        } else if (person.age == 31) {
            p1 = person
            ageParam = 21
        }
        false // it's false in order to keep iterate after P1 found
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is close to optimal. But it doesn't take *first* objects meeting criteria. For `listOf(Person(id=1, age=21), Person(id=2, age=21), Person(id=3, age=31))` it will return `p1 = Person(id=2, age=21)`.
To fix this you need to have additional comparsions with `null` in your conditional expressions (after implementing this, your second `if`-statement could be merged into branches of the first one to avoid repeating checks). Also, you can't use `break` inside `forEach` - it should be substituted with simple loop.
All together:

```kotlin
var p1: Person? = null
var p2: Person? = null
for (it in list) {
    if (p1 == null && it.age == 21) {
        p1 = it
        if (p2 != null) break
    } else if (p2 == null && it.age == 31) {
        p2 = it
        if (p1 != null) break
    }
}
```

To generalize this you may create extension function:

```kotlin
fun <T> Iterable<T>.takeFirstTwo(predicate1: (T) -> Boolean, predicate2: (T) -> Boolean): Pair<T?, T?> {
    var p1: T? = null
    var p2: T? = null
    for (it in this) {
        if (p1 == null && predicate1(it)) {
            p1 = it
            if (p2 != null) break
        } else if (p2 == null && predicate2(it)) {
            p2 = it
            if (p1 != null) break
        }
    }
    return p1 to p2
}

//Usage:
val is21 = { it: Person -> it.age == 21}
val is31 = { it: Person -> it.age == 31}
val (p1, p2) = list.takeFirstTwo(is21, is31)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [filter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collection-filtering.html) keyword to filter any collection

```
    val matches = list.filter { if (it.age == 21 || it.age == 31) }
```

`matches` will be a list where all `Person` objects have an age of 21 or 31.

Comment: how would he then select 2 of those records, with the guarantee that one meets condition 1 and the other one meets condition 2? Since this is the actual question.

Comment: How can you guarantee the original list meets this criteria?

Comment: you can't, neither does `.filter`, since if the original list doesn't meet the criteria, then the result of  `.filter` will be an empty list.

Comment: Well then I can't guarantee 2 Person objects, 1 with age 21 and age 31 :) I think this is the more Kotlin idiomatic way of doing this sort of thing

Comment: what about doing a `.find{}`? If it is there you'll get it (without iterating over all of the elements all the time, since `find` will stop at the first one found)

Comment: @KenWolf: What do you mean by guarantee? I do expect that there might not be such objects so it will be null

Comment: yes, but if it is not there, you don't have to do anything else. When doing `.filter` you don't know which of the conditions has been met for each resulting element (it might result in an empty list, a list full of `age ==21`, a list full of `age==31`, or an actual mix). So you still need to check the results of the `filter` again to get a single record for each condition (the requirements of the question). Otherwise this is just an incomplete answer at best.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is such a method in `List`, the closest statement would be get first match using `list.first{it.age == 21 || it.age == 31 }`, which will get the first item matching given predicate then breaks the loop, may be you can write your own extension to filter first `n` numbers

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.firstN(n: Int, predicate: (T) -> Boolean): List<T> {
    val output = ArrayList<T>()
    var count = 0
    for (element in this){
        if(count == n) break
        if (predicate(element)){
            count++
            output.add(element)
        }
    }
    return output
}
```

You can do below to get first two elements

```
with(list.firstN(2){ it.age == 21 || it.age == 31}){
     if(size == 2){
         val (p1, p2) = this
     }
}
```

Comment: issue with this is that it is possible for it to return `n` `Person` with `age == 21`, depending on the order of the elements in the list.

Comment: That could return 2 of age 21 or age 31 as @Alex.T points out

Comment: Yep I guess we have to maintain list of predicates and counts , so can target each criteria limit , doing it manual would be much better

Comment: @Jim btw, the solution from the question itself does the same thing, since the count++ can activated twice on the age==21 and then it will break from the loop.

Comment: @Alex.T: You are right. I just wanted to outline the code, I will correct that since it can be misleading

Comment: @Alex.T: Updated the post. Thanks for the pointer